# Is there anyway to find active user count for my Mac Appstore application?

Tags: macos, statistics, app-store

I recently had my free application published in Mac Appstore. I'm trying to find out how many users are actually using it. It looks like Apple only tells me downloads count.

Previously I had my own stats system showing both installs and daily active users. That's why I'm sure that sum of installations is not equal to total users count.

So my question is how can I find out daily active user count for my Appstore application without adding my own report system to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know nobody collects this kind of data at Apple for you. If you want to have such stats that differ from your download count, you'll have to use your own implementation or sites like [this service](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html).